# Installing Windows 7 with updates already installed

Tags: windows-7, automation, formatting, updates

A search of the titled question reveals "dual booting with XP" and other irrelevant dated forum posts.

I run a small business offering basic reformatting services, I have one reoccuring complaint after people get their computers back. Their computer does updates slowly (like 50-60 at a time or so) for weeks after they get it back.

It'd be great if there was a constantly updated DVD image of Windows 7 Home Pro so that my customers don't have to install updates every time they use their laptop for weeks after getting their machines back.

**My question:**

Does there exist an up-to-date installation image of windows 7 or just a faster way to install all the updates at once?

Comment: the process requires you to create 'slipstreamed' media (a disk) that contains the updates already on it. here is a tutorial for slipstreaming SP1 into a win7 install image: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/145343-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso-file.html

Comment: You could also just buy a Win7-SP1 disk. Probably has only 1/2 the updates as of 2014, but it is a start and they are not only done, but because it is tested as a whole item, it can be very reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could handle this.

You can do exactly what you're talking about by [slipstreaming the updates in to the Windows 7 install](https://www.google.com/?q=slipstream%20updates%20windows%207). The right and proper way to do this is using Microsoft provided tools, such as WAIK, and building an image. I think both these methods are heavy handed for a small business.

Give [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) a try. You can download all the updates before hand, and apply them after installation in one go. This should be substantially faster than the download, reboot, download, reboot cycle your users are currently experiencing.

Comment: I'm going to look into both approaches and report back.

Comment: WSUS Offline Updater still took about 3 hours to do its thing, and didn't install any updates from April 2014 and newer. I'm going to look into slipstreaming on my next customers computer.

Comment: Curious, did you download the updates before hand? It should download them once and then you should be able to install on multiple computers with downloading again.

Comment: I did, I can't recall the exact error message (Customer received their laptop yesterday), but yes I downloaded all the updates, was approximately 2 gbs. It wasn't that big of a deal, I just installed the updates the old school way. It didn't take too, too long. (Couple hundred updates). I do like that I can just go to the gym or go to sleep and almost all the updates are installed automatically.